# Как указать тип аргумента функции в python

Tags: python, типы

Я для аргумента asset и amount указал тип, а как теперь указать тип переменных у которых стоит дефолтное значение?

```
def createInvoice(self, asset: str, amount: str, 
                      description = None, 
                      hidden_message = None, 
                      paid_btn_name = None, 
                      paid_btn_url = None, 
                      payload = None: str, 
                      allow_comments = None, 
                      allow_anonymous = None, 
                      expires_in = None
                     ):
```

Comment: да точно так же как и всегда `description: Type = None, `

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы указать переменной дефолтное значение, можно воспользоваться следующим:

```
description: Type = None
```